# Bold / Italic doesn't work on custom fonts using PhantomJS

Tags: fonts, font-face, phantomjs

When I try to render a custom font with phantomJS, the bold and italic tags don't work / are not applied.

All my CSS is directly in the HTML template in the `<head>` in a `<style>` tag.

Here is what I have:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: userSelectedFont;
    src: url("/usr/share/fonts/dejavu/DejaVuSerif.ttf");
}
```

And then in my `<body>`:

```
<div style="font-family: userSelectedFont, sans-serif;"><strong><em>Test</em></strong></div>
```

But phantomJS generates this image:
[image: Good font but not in bold or italic]

It's definitely using the good font but not applying bold and italic.
Any idea ?

PS: If I delete the `style="font-family: userSelectedFont-7, sans-serif;"` part it works fine in bold and italic...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just found the solution. You need to provide a `font-style` and a `font-weight` to your `font-face`

Here is my final code:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'userSelectedFont';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    src: url("/usr/share/fonts/dejavu/DejaVuSerif.ttf");
}
```

Comment: Nice one. Even when you want bold text, you have to specify normal in the font-face, then bold on the actual selector

Answer (score 3):

I have been able to solve this problem in PhantomJS 2.x with CSS:

```
strong, b {font-weight: normal; -webkit-text-stroke: 0.05em;}
```

I apply a stroke to the font, which makes it look bold.

Answer (score 1):

Normal, bold, italic, and bold italic are separate TTF files, and you need to write a separate `@font-face` rule for each one:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'userSelectedFont';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    src: url(".../DejaVuSerif.ttf");
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'userSelectedFont';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: bold;
    src: url(".../DejaVuSerif-Bold.ttf");
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'userSelectedFont';
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: normal;
    src: url(".../DejaVuSerif-Italic.ttf");
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'userSelectedFont';
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: bold;
    src: url(".../DejaVuSerif-BoldItalic.ttf");
}
```

Then setting `font-family: "userSelectedFont"; font-weight: bold` (for instance) on some element will work as you expect.

This is not a bug in PhantomJS; it is how `@font-face` is specified to work.

Comment: No, it is not. You dont need to add separate fonts for different styling. Bolding for example, exists also as a css property that will make any font look bolder, regardles of defined fonts.

Here, take a quick look at this fiddle, with just one font (normal):
https://jsfiddle.net/ghzs1egj/1/

Every browser displays this properly, but not Phantom since 2.x versions were released. So it is clearly a bug.

Comment: Regardless of this being a bug or not, the solution worked pretty well for me. Thank you.